# Trying to extract a list of Unique Values from a field using python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have a number of columns in a number of tables withinh a FGDB where I need to extract the unique values for each column.

For Example: the values may be  [1,2,2,2,3,4], and I am trying to return [1,2,3,4]

I could do this job a number of other ways in ARCGIS  but I am trying to extend myself.

I have found a piece of python on the web that I think will do the job but I am struggling to get it to run (I keep getting an invalid syntax error as I keep getting the syntax error in line 3)  this will no doubt be a really simple user error.

Code Snippet below

```
import arcpy

def unique_values(r'N:\GISProjects\Landuse\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj'):
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
    return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})
```

This is the Error Message I get from sublime text:

```
 File "C:\Users\hawkinle\Desktop\STDTAS\Unique_Data.py", line 3
def unique_values(r'N:\GISProjects\Steve_Eastwood_Landuse\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj'):
                                                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

**Updates from Original Question**

I have now updated my code with the answer provided by below but am recieving a secondary error.

**New Code Snippet:**

```
import arcpy

def unique_values(table , field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

myValues = unique_values(r'N:\\GISProjects\\Landuse\\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\\Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj')

print (myValues)
```

I am getting a new error message related to a runtime error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hawkinle\Desktop\STDTAS\Unique_Data.py", line 7, in <module>
myValues = unique_values(r'N:\\GISProjects\\Steve_Eastwood_Landuse \Plant_Biosecurity_Project\\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\\Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj')
 File "C:\Users\hawkinle\Desktop\STDTAS\Unique_Data.py", line 4, in unique_values
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
RuntimeError: cannot open 'N:\\GISProjects\\Steve_Eastwood_Landuse\\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\\Holdings_Property_Merge'
```

[Finished in 8.0s with exit code 1]

I assume from the reading I have done that this relates to setting the env.workspace ?

[image: Just showing Proof that it exisist]

Comment: please [edit] your question to include your entire error message (as text)

Comment: Your new error shouldn't have anythign to do with the `env.workspace` I don't think.  Try either taking off the `r` before the path, or changing the `\\` to `\` in the path (and leave the `r` there).  Does that Geodatabase exist?

Comment: Are you trying to isolate all of the unique values in a field? For example, say you have the following values `[1,2,2,2,3,4]`, are you trying to return `[1,2,3,4]`. Please update the post to include this information.

Comment: @Midavalo did you meant changing the path tolook like this ?r'N: GISProjects _Landuse Plant_Biosecurity_Project ArcGIS_Online.gdb Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj'

Comment: @Aaron updated the  question for you.

Comment: @LeithHawkins I mean either make your path `r'N:\GISProjects\Landuse\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\Holdings_Property_Merge'` or remove the `r` and double each slash like `'N:\\GISProjects\\Landuse\\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\\Holdings_Property_Merge'`

Comment: I see the slashes disappeared from my earlier comment

Comment: Hmm still getting same errors with updated fields from both formats. Ill keep digging.

Comment: @LeithHawkins you are missing a slash - you have `N:\GISProjects` in your script and errors, but your screenshot as `N:\GIS\Projects` (note the slash between "GIS" and "Projects")

Comment: Thanks - fruther proof that im not very smart but I can lift heavy things.  I owe you a speights!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44508/discussion-between-leith-hawkins-and-midavalo).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've pretty much got it, you just need to specify the name of your parameters `table` and `field` in your function definition, and then pass those values when you call the function.  Also watch your indentation, as it's vital for Python.

```
def unique_values(table , field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

myValues = unique_values(r'N:\GISProjects\Landuse\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj')

print (myValues)
```

Basically this is saying that when you call the function `unique_values()` you'll pass values to two parameters, one called `table`, the other called `field`.  These are then used in your function.  When you call the function, in the line

```
myValues = unique_values(r'N:\GISProjects\Landuse\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj')
```

you are passing the values to these parameters.

This is the same as declaring your parameters separately and passing them to the cursor directly:

```
table = r'N:\GISProjects\Landuse\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\Holdings_Property_Merge'
field = 'LU_ALUMMaj'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
    myValues = sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

print myValues
```

Comment: ahh that makes sense , when you include the individual paramters below I get what you are saying thankyou! .  I am know moving up the chain of errors as I am getting a run time error which isnt allowing me to open the existing database.  Ill update my question.

Comment: Why does the sorted () line return just one unique instance of each value when the sorted() function returns duplicates if you run it on a simple list like ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']? I have been using this reply for some time and realized I did not understand why it works.

Comment: @DylanWarburg Because you're not passing a _list_ of values, you are passing a _set_.    If you add your list items above to a set, eg `set(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])`, it will return unique values `{'a', 'b'}`.  Using `sorted()` just returns them in sorted order as a simple set is unsorted.

Comment: If the field you are looking for unique values from is not a string, you should add: return sorted({str(row[0]) for row in cursor})

Answer (score 12):

I would advise using Python's built-in [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) function along with a [`SearchCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) as a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to find the unique values. You'll find this approach extremely efficient with large or small datasets:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\featureclass'

unique_values = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "some_field"))
```

Answer (score 5):

The following approach was published on https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/create-a-list-of-unique-field-values/ It is using arcpy and numpy and has a smaller memory footprint than the SearchCursor approach.

```
import arcpy
import numpy

def unique_values(table , field):
    data = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(table, [field])
    return numpy.unique(data[field]).tolist()

myValues = unique_values(r'N:\GISProjects\Landuse\Plant_Biosecurity_Project\ArcGIS_Online.gdb\Holdings_Property_Merge' , 'LU_ALUMMaj')

print (myValues)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `arcpy.Frequency_analysis()` quickly puts all the unique values from a field into a new table, which you can then use for cursor operations.  One single command to do what all these other solutions do and faster and easier.  As a bonus, you also get a count of how many times each value appears.

Answer (score 0):

open Python window in Arcgis Pro. make sure you have layer in ToC  and paste this  `print(*sorted(list(set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("layer name", "Column Name")))), sep="\n")`

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ey9NUNaP7k&t=3s

Comment: The list function is unnecessary since [sorted - Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) accepts an iterable and sets are iterable.