# (arcpy) Multiple TableSelect_analysis?

Tags: arcpy

```
arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(in_table, out_table, {where_clause})‍
```

**"Selects table records matching a Structured Query Language (SQL) expression and writes them to an output table."**

Using the `arcpy.TableSelect_analysis()` function I have this simple script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r'\\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\ModelBuilder\JaredTest.gdb'

#variables
intable = r"\\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\ModelBuilder\JaredTest.gdb\ElectionResults_Nov2016"
outtable = r"\\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\ModelBuilder\JaredTest.gdb\Results3"
where_clause = "ContestTitle = 'BALLOTS CAST - TOTAL'"

arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(intable, outtable, where_clause)‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

It selects all records named 'BALLOTS CAST - TOTAL' from the 'ContestTitle' column of my 'ElectionResults_Nov2016' table and writes them in the newly created 'Results3' table. 'BALLOTS CAST - TOTAL' is only one of 58 separate table record names.

How can I write all 58 to their own tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the unique values witin the field using a cursor like:

[Trying to extract a list of Unique Values from a field using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208430/trying-to-extract-a-list-of-unique-values-from-a-field-using-python)

Then loop through the unique value list:

```
unique_values = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(intable, "ContestTitle"))
# then loop through all unique values
for value in unique_values:
    where_clause = "ContestTitle = '{}'".format(value)
    # you may need to manipulate the value variable here to remove any
    # special characters or spaces that may cause issues in the fc table name
    outtable = r"\\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\ModelBuilder\JaredTest.gdb\{}".format(value)
    arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(intable, outtable, where_clause)‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

Comment: That worked great up to a point. It wrote four tables, but then threw an error: `ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output \\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\ModelBuilder\TEST folder\TEST.gdb\COUNTY BOARD MEMBER DISTRICT FOUR`   (note: I changed the output location)
 
It may be, as you said, because of the value variable. I'll look into it. But, overall it did as I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Table names cannot have spaces, use something like value.replace(' ','_') to replace blank space with underscore "_" character.