# Calculating individual Sum of multiple fields

Tags: arcpy, cursor, summarizing

I am trying to calculate the sum in each field in my list:

```
Cost_Adders = ["RR_CROSSING", "INTERSTATE", "RIVER"]
for Cost in Cost_Adders:
    where = f"Cost_Adders = {Cost}"
    CostAdder_count = sum([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Layer, Cost_Adders, where = f"Cost_Adders = {Cost}")])
    arcpy.AddMessage(f"{Cost} Layer: {CostAdder_count}")
```

but receive the error below:

> TypeError: 'where' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Is this due to a bad where clause?

Comment: The error says what the problem is, i.e., "invalid keyword."  There is no parameter named `where`, the parameter is named `sql_clause`

Comment: @Hornbydd  this still gives me the same error

Comment: @bixb0012 are you saying replace where with sql_clause?

Comment: I see the problem now, you need to review your logic, you are summing on RR_Crossing but you are also querying the data on it as well as interstate and river fields which frankly makes no sense.

Comment: @hBiery, yes, but after you fix the TypeError there will be logic-based errors as others have pointed out.

Comment: @bixb0012 realized I didnt need the where clause at all, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same code structure in [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/452889/196564) for [Error using ArcPy SearchCursor to get list of unique values in multiple fields - GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376746/error-using-arcpy-searchcursor-to-get-list-of-unique-values-in-multiple-fields/452889#452889) can be used in this type of situation.

```py
import arcpy
import collections

table =  # path to feature class or table, or name of layer or table view
fields = # list of field names to gather unique values

sums = collections.defaultdict(int)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        for i, value in enumerate(row):
            sums[cur.fields[i]] += value if value is not None else 0

for k, v in sums.items():
    print(f"Sum of {k} is {v}")
```